# Push Notification Delivery and Dismiss Callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Can we make a service call from the client side when a push notification is delivered or dismissed when the app is not active?

Also does APNS give any information on whether the notification is delivered at an individual level and is there any api we can use to query the delivery status report?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can detect delivery of remote notification if you send the `content-available` flag to `1` in the `aps` dictionary. If you set the key, `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method of the AppDelegate is called.

Also, from iOS 10 onwards, you can also detect dismissal of remote notifications. For that you need to implement UserNotifications Framework.

You need to perform the below steps for the same:

1. Use iOS 10 APIs to register the categories for remote notifications.
   You need to check `[[UNUserNotificaionCenter currentNotificationCenter] setNotificationCategories]` method for the same. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter
2. iOS 10 introduces a new class called `UNNotificationCategory` for encapsulating a category instance. You need to set the `CustomDismissAction` on the category instance to be able to receive the dismiss callback.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationcategory

3. Implement the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` protocol with the implementation of `userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:` method. This method will receive the callback to the dismiss action provided you perform the above steps.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate

Set your delegate to the UserNotificationCenter - `[[UNUserNotificaionCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = your_delegate_implementation`

4. Set the category with `CustomDismissAction` property in the payload.

```
    {
        "aps": {
            "alert": "joetheman",
            "sound": "default",
            "category": "my-custom-dismiss-action-category",
            "content-available":1
        },
        "message": "Some custom message for your app",
        "id": 1234
}
```

Comment: I was able to get dismiss callback working wiht this solution. Thanks!

Comment: the way you wrote it kinda implies that `customDismissAction` is used solely for the purpose of dismissing but that's not correct. It's just one of many purposes of having categories. Categories are useful for 1. Grouping actions 2. Adding a placeholder in case the user is hiding previews 3. other tweaks through the category Options such as your answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make a service call from the ios app when a notification is received when app is not active. Do this in:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    <#code#>
}
```

yes you can add additional key value pair in your push notification payload.

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "joetheman",
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "message": "Some custom message for your app",
    "id": 1234
}
```

Comment: This method is not call until user select that notification

Comment: @chiragshah you need to add content-available key to 1 inside aps to trigger the method on delivery.